# Write-Host is doubled after running as remote command

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, ps

I'm trying to run remote this code:

```
$servers = @("myserver.local")
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
#############
Write-Host "Test1:" "xxx";
hostname
Write-Host "Test2:" "yyy";
#############
} -ComputerName $servers
```

And getting this output:

```
Test1: xxx
Test1: xxx
myserver
Test2: yyy
Test2: yyy
```

Expected output:

```
Test1: xxx
myserver
Test2: yyy
```

As you can see, `Write-Host` output is doubled, but `hostname` is okay.
Why?

[image: VSCode screenshot]

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon I have only one server in $servers array.

Comment: Try pipping `Out-Host` after the command: `Invoke-Command { .... } -ComputerName ... | Out-Host`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still having this issue but I encountered same problem and the problem seems to be that one output comes from `Write-Host` and other from `Invoke-Command` as result of the command.

One of these two needs to be suppressed, it doesn't matter which one, following example code from your question suppresses output from `Invoke-Command`

```
$servers = @("myserver.local")
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
#############
Write-Host "Test1:" "xxx";
hostname
Write-Host "Test2:" "yyy";
#############
} -ComputerName $servers 6>$null
```

Note the `6>$null` given to `Invoke-Command` makes duplicate information stream to null, and only one is printed:

> Test1: xxx

> myserver

> Test2: yyy

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem. Your output is doubled because you are executing it in two of the servers. If you increase it , then the output will also increase.

The problem here is that the output is not coming as per each host respectively means there is a format/order issue.

Below is the sample as per the comment you made. I have taken one paramater to pass it inside the scriptblock of the remote system and captured the output in to the running PS session.

```
$hostname= 'RemoteComputer' #Input parameter

$results= Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($hostname)Write-Host "Test1:" "xxx"; #taken the same input inside the script block using param
    $out=hostname #Stored the result in the $out variable
    Write-Host "Test2:" "yyy";
    $out #printed the result
} -ComputerName $servers -ArgumentList $hostname  #Passed the parameter in the scriptblock argument so that it can go inside as param

$results
```

I have explained the lines with comments on each line for easy understanding.

Comment: "you are executing it in two of the servers." - how it can be possible if `$servers` array contains only 1 server? Why `hostname` is not doubled?

Comment: @rGA145: Hostname is getting printed in the remote computer's PS session and not coming outside. You need to do few tricks for that and pass the things as param and argument block. I will edit my answer and will update you. but you have to update the question as well